# How to get running maximum in Stata?

Tags: algorithm, max, stata

I would like to get the running maximum by writing Stata code.

I think I am quite close:

```
gen ctrhigh`iv' = max(ctr, L1.ctr, L2.ctr, L3.ctr, ..., L`iv'.ctr)
```

As you can see, my data are time series and `` `iv' `` represents the window (e.g. 5, 10 or 200 days)

The only problem is that you cannot pass a varlist or string containing numbers to `max`. E.g. the following is not possible:

```
local ivs 5 10 50 100 200
foreach iv in `ivs' {
    local vals
    local i = 1
    while (`i' <= `iv') {
        vals "`vals' `i'"
        local ++i
    }
    gen ctrhigh`iv' = max(varlist vals) //not possible
}
```

How would I achieve this instead?

*Example of quickly computing a running standard deviation*

```
* standard deviation of ctr, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Rapid_calculation_methods *
gen ctr_sq = ctr^2
by tid: gen ctr_cum = sum(ctr) if !missing(ctr)
by tid: gen ctr_sq_cum = sum(ctr_sq) if !missing(ctr_sq)
foreach iv in $ivs {
    if `iv' == 1 continue
    by tid: gen ctr_sum = ctr_cum - L`iv'.ctr_cum if !missing(ctr_cum) & !missing(L`iv'.ctr_cum)
    by tid: gen ctr_sq_sum = ctr_sq_cum - L`iv'.ctr_sq_cum if !missing(ctr_sq_cum) & !missing(L`iv'.ctr_sq_cum)
    by tid: gen ctrsd`iv' = sqrt((`iv' * ctr_sq_sum - ctr_sum^2) / (`iv'*(`iv'-1))) if !missing(ctr_sq_sum) & !missing(ctr_sum)
    label variable ctrsd`iv' "Rolling std dev of close ticker rank by `iv' days."
    drop ctr_sum ctr_sq_sum
}
drop ctr_sq ctr_cum ctr_sq_cum
```

Note: this is not an exact sd, it's an approximation. I realize that this is very different from a maximum, but this may serve as an illustration on how to deal with large data computations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I can pass a string of arguments to max, like so:

```
* OPTION 1: compute running max by days *
foreach iv in $ivs {

    * does not make sense for less than two days *
    if `iv' < 2 continue

    di "computing running max for ctr interval `iv'"

    * set high for this amount of days *
    local vars "ctr"
    forval i = 1 / `iv' {
        local vars "`vars', L`i'.ctr"
    }
    by tid: gen ctrh`iv' = max(`vars')

}


* OPTION 2: compute running max by days, ensuring that entire range is nonmissing *
foreach iv in $ivs {

    * does not make sense for less than two days *
    if `iv' < 2 continue

    di "computing running max for ctr interval `iv'"

    * set high for this amount of days *
    local vars "ctr"
    local condition "!missing(ctr)"
    forval i = 1 / `iv' {
        local vars "`vars', L`i'.ctr"
        local condition "`condition' & !missing(L`i'.ctr)"
    }
    by tid: gen ctrh`iv' = max(`vars') if `condition'

}
```

This computes very quickly and does exactly what I need.

However, if you need an arbitrarily large window I think you should resort to Nick's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is time series data and implies that you have `tsset` the data. You don't say whether you also have panel or longitudinal structure. I will assume the worst and assume the latter as it doesn't make the code much worse. So, suppose `tsset id date`. In fact, that's irrelevant to the code here except to make explicit my assumption that `id` is an identifier and `date` a time variable.

An unattractive way to do this is to loop over observations. Suppose window is set to 42.

```
  local window = 42 
  gen max = . 
  tsset id date 
  quietly forval i = 1/`=_N' { 
      su ctr if inrange(date, date[`i'] - `window', date[`i']) & id == id[`i'], meanonly 
      replace max = r(max) in `i' 
  }
```

So, in words as well: `summarize` values of `ctr` if `date` within window *and* it's in the same panel (same `id`), and put the maximum in the current observation.

The `meanonly` option is not well named. It calculates some other quantities besides the mean, and the maximum is one. But you do want the `meanonly` option to make `summarize` go as fast as possible.

See my 2007 paper on events in intervals, freely available at http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0033

I say unattractive, but this approach does have the advantage that it is easy to work with once you understand it.

I am not setting up an expression with lots of arguments to `max()`. You said 200 as an example and nothing stated that you might not ask for more, so far as I can see there may be no upper limit on window length, but there will be a limit on how complicated that expression can be.

If I think of a better way to do it, I'll post it. Or someone else will....

Comment: Hi Nick, I do apologize for not being complete. I forgot to mention that it's longitudinal (panel) data, which seems to be in line with your code. Unfortunately I have 4 million observations, and therefore need to compute `4m - window` maximums. As a consequence your code has been running for many hours now without any results (using 4 i7 cores). Do you think there is a way to speed up the process? For example, I managed to quickly calculate a running standard deviation for the 4m obs using some arithmetic trick. In case you're interested, it's in my original post now.

Comment: Also, I won't need a window larger than 120 (the 200 was just hypothetical).

Comment: I feel almost ashamed for figuring out such a simple solution, which I am quite sure of you know as well. Anyway, I figured out how to do this in a matter of seconds using the `max` operator. I guess you recommended the above because I didn't mention the limit on my window. Thank you very much for the assistance though, I would not have gotten there without it. Just one question: do you think I should add a `if !missing(L1.ctr) & !missing(L2.ctr) & ... & !missing(LN.ctr)` after the `max` command if I only want it to compute when the entire range is nonmissing?

Comment: `max()` ignores missings unless all its arguments are missing, so extra conditions `!missing()` are not needed. (`max()` is a function, not a command.)

Comment: That'd imply that I do need the missing conditions, because I do not want it to ignore missings but instead return missing when any of the variables given are missing. Do you know if there are more mathematical functions available, e.g. to calculate the mean and standard deviation of a list of numbers, or maybe a user written addon? These functions are very useful for fast running computations.

Comment: You risk confusion here between Stata functions and Stata commands. Functions can't be added by users. I don't think user-written commands could be written to be faster than `summarize` or the kind of code you have written using inbuilt functions such as `sum()`. The only scope for going faster is to turn to Mata.

Comment: Thanks again. This makes me wonder if Stata is meant for big data or not :)

Comment: Too big a question to be answered in a comment... http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?limits documents size limits.